# Sync desktop application with android application

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I want to raise an event from my Android application to my desktop application which is in Java. Can I do so? If yes, which API to use? Any examples or code snippets?

Comment: Can you add more details? What is your use case? What's your intended way of communication? What have you already done/tried?

Answer (score 1):

Both android and desktop applications are clients. Two clients can talk to each other via server or at least initialize their connection via server that is running on pre-defined location (IP address). So, you need some server that allows to do this.

You can probably use (or abuse) some 3rd party servers for this. For example if your desktop application "knows" the phone number it can send SMS via one of available web services. The android application will catch the SMS and take information from its text. You probably can use Skype installed on your machine or email to send messages among applications too. But better way is to develop your own server that exposes RESTful API and use it for the negotiation.

Comment: can i use sockets in android to trigger my desktop application??